# Match a string and get what is after the match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this content from a torrent file

```
d8:announce39:http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce13:announce-listll39:http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceel44:http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceee7:comment29:Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com13:creation datei1539860537e4:infod6:lengthi1999503360e4:name30:ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso12:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces76280
```

or I can have also

```
d8:announce39:http://torrent.centos.org:6969/announce13:announce-listll39:http://torrent.centos.org:6969/announceel44:http://ipv6.torrent.centos.org:6969/announceee7:comment27:CentOS x86_64 LiveGNOME ISO10:created by13:mktorrent 1.013:creation datei1526053398e4:infod5:filesld6:lengthi1388314624e4:pathl34:CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.isoeed6:lengthi454e4:pathl11:sha1sum.txteed6:lengthi1314e4:pathl15:sha1sum.txt.asceed6:lengthi598e4:pathl13:sha256sum.txteed6:lengthi1458e4:pathl17:sha256sum.txt.asceee4:name30:CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-180412:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces52980:
```

I want to retrieve the name part like `ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso`
Here is what I tried but it check the full content :

```
$.get('search', function(data) {
    var lines = data.split("\n");
    var $result = false
    var url_check 
    var search= [];
    $.each(lines, function(n, data) {
        search.push(data)
    })
}).done(function(search){
    search= search.split("\n");
    var $result = [];
    $.each(search, function(n, search) {
        var regex = new RegExp('^(?=.*' + search.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&').split(/\\?[\s,_.:*-]+/).join(')(?=.*') + ')', 'gi');
        if(regex.test(url_check) === true){
            $result.push('true');
        }else{
            $result.push('false');
        }
    })
    console.log($result)
    if($result.indexOf("true") !== -1){
        alert('Found !') 
    }else {
        alert('Not found !');
    }
})
```

Content of the file **search** :

```
*Ubuntu.18*
*centos 7*
```

Comment: Are there always exactly 2 digits that come before the `:piece`, like `12:piece`? (for the second example text, I assume you'd want `CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804`, right?)

Comment: Will this `ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso` always followed by `piece`  ?

Comment: Nop It can be different

Comment: Then how would you distinguish the part of the name (eg `1804`) from the trailing numbers (the `12`)? Can't match the name there and nothing else without there being some pattern to it

Comment: But yes name is fallowed by piece

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/yiHhn0/1 or just split on the `:` and count. I'm pretty sure there's a rule for the parts.

Comment: Something like `(?<=:name).*?(?=:piece)` ?

Comment: @Thefourthbird results in additionally matching the trailing `12` after the `.iso`, which I don't think is desirable (but without knowing the logic behind those trailing numbers, don't think the problem is solvable as presented)

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right, removing the comment

Comment: see this https://regex101.com/r/Pkl6mo/1/ your desired output is in captured group

Comment: Tank you for all suggestion but which one is the suitable ?

Comment: @executable Like I said, the question isn't exactly solvable given the current info - without knowing the logic to separate the undesirable trailing digits from the content of the name, there's no way to write a regex that will work in the general case. Please check to see if there's any logic to the number of trailing digits

Comment: I don't know how the content are generated, it's the content of a .torrent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [BitTorrent specification](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding), those trailing digits match the *length of the following string*. For example

```
ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

is 30 characters long, thus the number that comes before it is 30:

```
30:ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso
```

So, a pure regex solution won't really work, at least not in any concise fashion. You could extract the `name<digits>:` and the *rest of the string* following it, and then in Javascript use `slice` to extract `<digits>` number of characters after the colon:

```js
const input = [
  'd8:announce39:http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce13:announce-listll39:http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceel44:http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announceee7:comment29:Ubuntu CD releases.ubuntu.com13:creation datei1539860537e4:infod6:lengthi1999503360e4:name30:ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso12:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces76280',
  'd8:announce39:http://torrent.centos.org:6969/announce13:announce-listll39:http://torrent.centos.org:6969/announceel44:http://ipv6.torrent.centos.org:6969/announceee7:comment27:CentOS x86_64 LiveGNOME ISO10:created by13:mktorrent 1.013:creation datei1526053398e4:infod5:filesld6:lengthi1388314624e4:pathl34:CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.isoeed6:lengthi454e4:pathl11:sha1sum.txteed6:lengthi1314e4:pathl15:sha1sum.txt.asceed6:lengthi598e4:pathl13:sha256sum.txteed6:lengthi1458e4:pathl17:sha256sum.txt.asceee4:name30:CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-180412:piece lengthi524288e6:pieces52980:'
];

function getName(str) {
  const match = str.match(/:name(\d+):(.+)$/);
  if (!match) {
    return console.log('No name found');
  }
  const [, length, rest] = match;
  console.log(
    rest.slice(0, length)
  );
}
input.forEach(getName)
```

If there may be line-terminators in the string, then `(.+)$` won't work because `.` does not match newlines - either remove the `$`, or, if there may be newlines in the name that you want to match, use `([\s\S]+)$` instead, to match *any* character, including newlines.

Comment: Using the function I'm getting `str.match is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: Sounds like the input string didn't match the `:name\d+:` pattern, you can add a test for the truthyness of the match object before destructuring

Comment: I have this result if I log like `console.log('ok' + str)` in the function https://i.imgur.com/4QqrHD7.png. I don't get what is wrong, it's retreiving well the string. Instead of `const input` can youshow how to use it on a simple string ?

Comment: Sounds like the rest of the string contains either `\r` or `\n`s, which `.` won't match - see edit, use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` to match literally any character

Comment: Thank you that was the issue

Comment: The function `getName` doesn't work properly on IE11 because of this line `const [, length, rest] = match;`

Comment: You can use Babel to automatically transpile ES6+ syntax down to ES5 if you want obsolete browsers to understand your code. The equivalent of this line would be `var length = match[1]; var rest = match[2];`

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer